# Mapping Typescript Enums by their keys without using a Map?

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

Have the following Enum instances:

```
export enum TopicCategories {
    GUIDES = 'Guides',
    TASKS = 'Tasks',
    CONCEPTS = 'Concepts',
    FORMULAS = 'Formulas',
    BLOGS = 'Blogs'
}

export enum TopicTypes {
    GUIDES = 'guide',
    TASK = 'task',
    CONCEPT = 'concept',
    FORMULA = 'formula',
    BLOG = 'blog'
}

export const topicCategoryToTopicTypeMap:Map<TopicCategories, TopicTypes> = new Map();

topicCategoryToTopicTypeMap.set(TopicCategories.BLOGS, TopicTypes.BLOG);
```

The `topicCategoryToTopicTypeMap:Map` instance will allow me to get the `TopicType.BLOG` using the `TopicCategory.BLOG` as a key value.

Is there a way to do this directly using only the `Enum` instances.  In other words is it possible to eliminate the `Map` instance and perform the mapping directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  const categoryToTopic = { "Guides" : "guide", /*...*/ };

  type TopicCategories = keyof typeof categoryToTopic;
  type TopicTypes = (typeof categoryToTopic)[TopicCategories];
```

Not quite. enums only work well with primitives, therefore you can't directly store more data on the enums.